# Generating log-normal random walks

Tags: r

wolframalpha 
can generate log-normal random walks based on historical parameters 
for 6 months, 1 year, 2 years ahead

for example the GSPC index:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GSPC

I was wondering how I could do this in R and I would be greatful for some guidance.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC", from ="2000-01-01")
```

Comment: Has your free trial to the Wolfram viewer expired? http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MarkovVolatilityRandomWalks/

Comment: something like `oldsteps <- diff(log(oldata)); exp(cumsum(rnorm(n_days,mean(oldsteps),sd(oldsteps))))` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have filled out the code below.

Answer (score 2):

How can I improve this to allow the
 volatility to change through time according to a simple Markov chain?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC", from ="2000-01-01")

oldata <-GSPC[,6]
oldata <-na.omit(oldata)

lastprice <-tail(olddata,1)
oldsteps <- tail(diff(log(oldata)),-1)
head(oldsteps)
n_days =100
percent <- exp(cumsum(rnorm(n_days,mean(oldsteps), apply(oldsteps, 2, sd))))
path2 <- exp(cumsum(rnorm(n_days,mean(oldsteps), apply(oldsteps, 2, sd))))
path3 <- exp(cumsum(rnorm(n_days,mean(oldsteps), apply(oldsteps, 2, sd))))

paths <- data.frame(T=c(1:100),path1,path2,path3 )

plot1 <- ggplot(data=paths, aes(x=T,y=percent )) + geom_line()
plot1 <- plot1+ geom_line(aes(x=T,y=path2))+  geom_line(aes(x=T,y=path3))
plot1 <- plot1+ ggtitle("pathways")
plot1
```

Comment: Have you been able to improve what you have since you posted this? I'm trying to do the same thing and am very interested in your solution.